# Chronicle Queue

Tags: kubernetes, queue, chronicle

Chronicle Queue:
How to sink between two queue in two different pods?

Synchronised between two queue in different pods?

Now considering there are two kubernetes pod writing data to Chronicle Queue on local file path
Who to synchronised the queue so that both will be having same data
When ever data is pushed in either one of them?

So that bot api using will be updated with same data.

And also consider if load is more and one more pod comes but the 3 pod with new queue also need be synchronised with first two pod queue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Chronicle Queue supports concurrent writers. You don't need to do anything special to have multiple appenders to the same queue.
If you have multiple containers they need to be on the same physical machine and map the same folder.

However network mounted folders don't work as they don't provide any guarantees on visibility